# How to access an API output file using an IP address?

Tags: php, python-3.x, api

We have an API (written in Python) running on Azure VM server, which takes a file url as input and generates a .png thumbnail file as output. We have an application running on another server, which tries to access this output. However, I somehow cannot access the output file.

The input to the API looks something like this:

```
 http://ipaddress:port/getthumbnail/file_server_url.doc
```

The API output looks something like this:

```
/home/they/pdfmaker_thumbnail/LTnHeFcR6dm.png
```

I have two questions (1) How do I access this .png file? (2) How could I access this file using an IP address?

The API is written in Python. The application that is trying to access the output url is written in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the web server you are using.If it is an apache httpd server, its default web directory is /var/www/html.You can put the file to access in this directory and access it simply via

> http://"ipaddress"/"filetoaccess"

.
Its usually a bad idea to expose the inner directory structure as your server might be vulnerable to attacks

Comment: Thanks. The webserver is an Azure VM server. I have added this to the question body also.

Comment: You might want to expose another api which takes the filename only and streams the file to the api consumer